# how to make a for loop work with a async.parallel()

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous, promise

I am using Sails, Waterline and Async library

```
function Outerfunction(listOfProducts) {
  var salesOrderId = 1; //some id
  var prom = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < listOfProducts.length; i++) {
    var qty = listOfProducts[i].quantity;
    var prod = listOfProducts[i].productName;
    var update = function(qty, prod, SalesOrderId) {
      CardImages.update({
          where: {
            productName: prod,
            isSold: false,
            readyToSell: true
          }
        }, {
          order: SalesOrderId,
          isSold: true
        })
        .exec(function(err, updatedRecords) {
          if (err) return err;
          return updatedRecords;
        });
    }
    prom.push(update);
  }
  async.parallel(prom, function(err, result) {

    //this callback never gets called
    console.log("database calls done");
  });
}
```

I am trying to update database with a for loop, this code works fine and updates the database but but my callback with `async.parallel` won't get called when all the records are updated.

Comment: `async.parallel` does take an array of *functions*. What does `exec` return? Given that you've tagged this with [promise], it seems you expect it to return a promise (afaik only if you pass no callback to `exec`) - so you want to use `Promise.all(prom).then(…)`, and shouldn't use async.js at all!

Comment: Or 
stick with `async`, 
purge any notion of promises, 
change member name "proms" to "tasks", and 
modify the functions pushed onto `tasks` to conform with [the documentation](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel)

Comment: instead of using a for loop i used a function, a counter and a callback but its slow and i am still looking for a solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `async.map`, which will apply an asynchronous function to each element in an array, and call back with an array of results. I can't test this, but something like this should work:

```
function OuterFunction(listOfProducts) {
  var salesOrderId = 1;  // some id

  async.map(listOfProducts, function (product, done) {
    // for each product, update its DB entry
    CardImages.update({
      productName: product.productName,
      isSold: false,
      readyToSell: true
    }, {
      order: salesOrderId,
      isSold: true
    }).exec(done);  // indicate that async work is done
  }, function (err, result) {
    // all finished
    console.log('database calls done');
  });
}
```

Note that this solution *does not use Promises at all*. This is simply callback-based asynchronous work.

---

I have not worked with Waterline, but based on what I quickly found in the (rather bad) documentation, this is also a possible solution:

```
function OuterFunction(listOfProducts) {
  var salesOrderId = 1;  // some id
  // extract product names
  var productNames = listOfProducts.map(function (product) {
    return product.productName;
  });

  // update in bulk
  CardImages.update({
    productName: productNames,
    isSold: false,
    readyToSell: true
  }, {
    order: salesOrderId,
    isSold: true
  }).exec(function (err, results) {
    // all finished
    console.log('database calls done');
  });
}
```

Translated to SQL, the first solution would emit (roughly)

```sql
UPDATE table SET isSold = TRUE, readyToSell = FALSE
WHERE productName = 'product 1' AND isSold = FALSE AND readyToSell = TRUE;

UPDATE table SET isSold = TRUE, readyToSell = FALSE
WHERE productName = 'product 2' AND isSold = FALSE AND readyToSell = TRUE;

UPDATE table SET isSold = TRUE, readyToSell = FALSE
WHERE productName = 'product 3' AND isSold = FALSE AND readyToSell = TRUE;

...
```

and the second would emit the more efficient

```sql
UPDATE table SET isSold = TRUE, readyToSell = FALSE
WHERE productName IN ('product 1', 'product 2', 'product 3', ...)
  AND isSold = FALSE AND readyToSell = TRUE;
```